# Destructuring with function argument

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I was trying our object destruction while passing it in function argument where I have:

```
config: {
    redshift: {
        connection: {
            clusterid: null,
            host: null,
            port: 5439,
            user: null,
            database: null,
            iamrole: null,
            ssl: true
        },
        query: {
            slotlimit: 50,
            username: null
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have sample.js where I have function which uses the config object:

```
function someFunc({clusterId: clusterid, iamRole: iamrole}) {
// do something with clusterId and iamRole not clusterid or iamrole
}
```

Then I have index.js where am passing the above config directly as:

```
someFunc(config.redshift.connection)
```

Am getting undefined for the above as I got to know we cannot use destructing like `someFunc({clusterId: clusterid, iamRole: iamrole})`
while i want to use camel-cased variables inside my function instead of doing
`someFunc({clusterid, iamrole})` and then use it.

Learning node and need some help from the community. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the key and resulting parameter names swapped. Refer to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names) and read the section on object destructuring assignments to new variable names. Below is a working example.

```js
config = {
    redshift: {
        connection: {
            clusterid: null,
            host: null,
            port: 5439,
            user: null,
            database: null,
            iamrole: null,
            ssl: true
        },
        query: {
            slotlimit: 50,
            username: null
        }
    }
};

function someFunc({clusterid: clusterId, iamrole: iamRole}) {
    // do something with clusterId and iamRole not clusterid or iamrole
    console.log(clusterId, iamRole);
}

someFunc(config.redshift.connection);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Klaycon 